# Retrieving XML node attributes and values

Tags: c#, xml

Here is a quick one for anyone who is familiar with parsing XML in C#

I have an XML file as below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral >
        <section name="Proxy.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Proxy.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MaxLogs" serializeAs="String">
                <value>10</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MaxArchives" serializeAs="String">
                <value>3</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="IpAddress" serializeAs="String">
                <value>COMPUTER2</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Port" serializeAs="String">
                <value>4050</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Index" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
        </Proxy.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I just want to read the attributes, and parse the name e.g "Port" but also retrieve the value set, in this case "4050".

I have a small snippet of code that returns the nodes to console output;

```
string path = "C:\\Path\\To\\XML.exe.config";

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);

var jproxy = xdoc.DescendantNodes();

foreach (var dn in jproxy)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dn.NextNode);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

And also a small class that I thought would be handy to store the list of results in;

```
public class Proxy
{
    public string MaxLogs { get; set; }
    public string MaxArchives { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }

}
```

Disclaimer:

I have researched most of the solutions available on here and other sites but it just isn't clicking for me at the moment. I know it's easier than I think and you can use XPath, Linq etc. but any help for this particular problem would be much appreciated.

If you have any suggestions for the best path for me to take in future for working with XML, I'm open to suggestion too as it is something I have struggled with in the past e.g use Linq or XPath or all of them?

Cheers

Comment: Your xml sample is malformed, the section group and section elements are missing the closing double quotes in their attribute values.

Comment: I had to anonymize it, but good spotting all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would give you all data in a KeyValuePair list. To fill that in class you provided you would either have to use reflection or swtich/case, nothing else I could think of that would be bit more generic:

```
            var proxies = (from i in xDoc.Descendants()
                       where i.Name.LocalName == "setting"
                       select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i.Attribute("name").Value, i.Element("value").Value)).ToList();
```

EDIT: I have always used LINQ to manipulate and query XML documents (similar to code above) and you can use XPath with it as well and it covered all scenarios I needed.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you very much. I'll work on getting the values added now and update the question with the solution. Cheers for that, I owe you a beer!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)